# How to access custom Object in twig i Symfony?

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

Inside a controller I check if user has access to a video if not AccessDeniedHttpException is thrown.

```
//check if user has access to this asset or not
if(!$this->get("asset.access_manager")->hasAccess($asset)){
   throw new AccessDeniedHttpException($this->get("translator")->trans("exception.asset.access.unauthorized"));
}
```

how can I pass $asset object which contains all information about the video to the Twig which is used by exception to show message?
 By accessing $asset object I can print information about video on Exception page.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check the permission (role?) I think the better way is:

```
{% if app.user.username is defined and is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN') %}
     //some awesome code here
{% else %}
     //without permission here
{% endif %}
```

First check if the user exist and later check his role.

Some documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html)

Comment: I know this, not just to user, we also have access to the Request and Session object and environment also. But this is not what I have asked about. Thank u.